# How to resolve the issue that optimizer.step() doesn't work

Tags: python, pytorch

fellows, I am a beginner of learning Deep Learning, I am trying to construct a new algorithm by combining the ResNet and the Bingham distribution, but I failed to get the features of this network since the code optimizer.step() didn't work which confused me a lot. My code snippet is pasted as follows.

```
wb = SummaryWriter("runs/tless_logs_1")
for epoch in range(config.dataset_train_test.epoch_num):
    verbose = epoch%5==0 or epoch==config.dataset_train_test.epoch_num-1
    log_train = loggers.get_train_logger(epoch,verbose)
    model.train()
    print(model.parameters)
    for i, (image, class_idx,q_r) in enumerate(train_loader):
        target_train_rotation = q_r.float().to(device)
        target_train_rotation = target_train_rotation.unsqueeze(dim=1)
        target_train_trans = torch.zeros((target_train_rotation.shape[0],1,4)).float().to(device)
        target_train = torch.cat((target_train_rotation, target_train_trans),dim=2).to(device)
        target_train = target_train.squeeze(dim=1)
        #print(target_train.shape)
        input_image = image.float().to(device)
        #input_image.requires_grad_(True)
        class_idx_device = class_idx.to(device)
        output = model(input_image,class_idx_device)
        print("output: ", output)
        
        loss_caonima = loss_fn(target_train, output,device)
        
        loss_cnm = torch.mean(loss_caonima)
        print("loss: ", loss_cnm)
        opt.zero_grad()
        loss_cnm.backward(retain_graph=True)
        opt.step()

        log_train.add_samples(target_train_rotation.squeeze(dim=1),output,loss_cnm.item(),class_idx)
        train_loss = loss_cnm.item()
        avg_loss+= train_loss
        iter+=1
        #avg_loss+= train_loss
        
        #if epoch==3:
        #    learning_rate=learning_rate*0.1
            #opt = optim.Adam(model.parameters(),lr=learning_rate)
        #    opt = optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate,momentum=0.9)
        #if (epoch+1)%4==0:
        #    learning_rate = learning_rate/10
        #    opt = optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate,momentum=0.9)
            #opt = optim.Adam(model.parameters(),lr=learning_rate)
        if iter%50==0:
            wb.add_scalar("training loss", avg_loss/50,iter)
            wb.add_scalar("likelihood", -avg_loss/50,iter)
            avg_loss=0.0
    log_train.show_tensorboard()
    print("epoch: {}, train loss: {}".format(epoch,train_loss))
```

The loss curve keeps being the same no matter if I uncomment the code block

```
            loss_cnm = torch.mean(loss_caonima)
            print("loss: ", loss_cnm)
            opt.zero_grad()
            loss_cnm.backward(retain_graph=True)
            opt.step()
```

Comment: Please, define "didn't work". Did you get any error? If so, please provide the complete traceback.

Comment: Yeah, I just check the network parameters where they are unchanged during running my code, as a result, I suppose that my self-defined gradient method has something wrong.